# Keras layer keyword not understood

Tags: tensorflow, keras, layer

In despite if several lectures on the forum, I can't fix my problem. Why does my code return :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-bd4a70a33726> in <module>()
----> 1 dd_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab/project/liver/firts_model.h5")

16 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs, error_message)
    806   for kwarg in kwargs:
    807     if kwarg not in allowed_kwargs:
--> 808       raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)
    809 
    810 

TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'output_shape')
```

with my class :

```
class Deconvolution3D(Layer):
  def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, strides, outshape):
    super().__init__()
    self.filters = filters
    self.strides = strides
    self.kernel_size = kernel_size
    self.output_shape_ = outshape
    

  def build(self, in_shape):
    assert len(in_shape) == 5
    self.in_shape = in_shape
    self.init = initializers.get('glorot_uniform')
    w_shape = self.kernel_size + (self.filters, in_shape[-1])
    self.w = self.add_weight(shape=w_shape, initializer=self.init, name="W")
    self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(1,1,1,self.filters), initializer="zero", name="B")
  
  def compute_output_shape(self, in_shape):
    return (None,) + self.output_shape_[1:]

  def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
    return tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(inputs, self.w, output_shape=self.output_shape_, strides=self.strides, padding="SAME", name="C") + self.b


  def get_config(self):
    config = super().get_config().copy()
    config.update({
        'output_shape' : self.output_shape_,
        'filters' : self.filters,
        'strides' : self.strides,
        'kernel_size' : self.kernel_size
    })
    
    return config
```

The attribute "out_shape" seems to be incorrect whereas the others (filters, strides) are good.

Comment: What forum are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `__init__`, if you use a variable name in your `get_config`, the exact same name must be used for that parameter in your `__init__`:

```
class Deconvolution3D(Layer):
  def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, strides, output_shape):
    super().__init__()
    self.filters = filters
    self.strides = strides
    self.kernel_size = kernel_size
    self.output_shape_ = output_shape
```

This is because the dictionary you make and return in `get_config` will be later deserialized and the keys will be passed as keyword arguments, meaning the keys in the dictionary will have to match your constructor `__init__` function parameter names.

Comment: Thanks for your help but there is always the same issue :

Comment: @rj17 You need to clarify what is "the same issue".

Comment: @rj17 You probably need to retrain your model since your old model has the previous definition of the class inside.

Comment: How can I (retrain) my old model on GColab ? I have tried to restart environment and kernel but always the same sentence "TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'output_shape')"